# mod_rewrite multiple statements with different out comes

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to write a .htaccess file and wanting to fulfill the following conditions:

- /$1/ will do index.php?page=$1
- /users/$1 will do index.php?page=users&id=$1 (where $1 is a number)

So I thought the following would work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^users/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=users&id=$1 [L]
```

However, it just seems to only do the first and I can't the second statement to work

Comment: Is /users/ always followed by numbers, because that's the only thing your rule is set to detect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that it conflicts with HTML5 push stating, even though usually the url could be requested despite being a permalink the html5 push state is somehow overriding it (even though it shouldn't!)

Answer (score 0):

Well so when I have done these I start mine with /

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/users/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=users&id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The path matched by RewriteRule _never_ starts with a `/` when in .htaccess context, because the leading slash gets stripped out before already.